# Add link hover colour with javascript and not css

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, hover

I use typeface.js for the few lines of text that is on my website, since I had some issues getting the wanted font to work in all browsers.  Using this the regular a:hover or similar CSS is non-effective, but I have managed to remove the underlines.

I am looking for a way to do this in js, and have tried out the ways that this forum have offered, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431046/changing-link-color-in-javascript-rather-than-csshover-works-in-jsfiddle-n).

I am fairly new to js, but try my best.  Any help is appreciated, and if you have other suggestions i am open to them!

The accordion menu's HTML

```
<div class="mH"
onclick="toggleMenu('menu1')">PORTFOLIO</div>
<div id="menu1" class="mL">
<a class="mO" href="pages/portraits.html">portraits</a>
<a class="mO" href="pages/thezoo.html">the zoo</a>
</div>

<div class="mH"
onclick="toggleMenu('menu2')">COMMERCIAL</div>
<div id="menu2" class="mL">
<a class="mO" href="pages/video.html">video</a>
<a class="mO" href="pages/photography.html">photography</a>
<a class="mO" href="pages/designillustration.html">design & illustration</a>
</div>

<div class="mH"
onclick="toggleMenu('menu3')">TRAVEL</div>
<div id="menu3" class="mL">
<a class="mO" href="pages/tanzania.html">tanzania</a>
</div>

</div>
```

The accordion menu's JS 
`function toggleMenu(objID) {
    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    var ob = document.getElementById(objID).style;
    ob.display = (ob.display == 'block')?'none': 'block';
    }`

Comment: Why do you want to use JS as opposed to CSS to change on hover?

Comment: Because the typeface.js does not support hover in CSS.  I use the typeface.js (for rendering text, check it out: http://typeface.neocracy.org/).  With the typeface.js my font is compatible and looks the same in all browsers - which was not the case just "linking" to it on googlefonts, the font then changed with different browsers.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399484/how-to-render-segoe-ui-font-in-different-navigators-and-oss/14475188#14475188 to see hot to properly add fonts to webpage. You should also Google for `font-face`to check how it should be done.

Comment: @bumerang - This would require the user to "download" the font from my website wouldn't it?  The typeface.js works as if the user already has the font installed.  But hot tip, I'll check it out for sure!

Comment: You are right about downloading fonts, but it's transparently as downloading `CSS` files, so user don't know about it. But when You use JavaScript font it have to: 1. Download JavaScript main file, and font file (which can be bigger than normal font file) 2. Check content for places to change; 3. replace the selected content

Comment: @bumerang - Great explanation!  I'll redo the font part of the site, and post the result for any other users curious about the same thing.  Thanks for helping a newbie along!

Comment: @Fred Berentsen - I'm glad that I could help

Comment: Had problems with the suggested method (likely due to my knowledge), and still looking for answers on how this can be done with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has gone unanswered as the question itself, but there are other solutions that work better.  I just didn't know them.

Ended up using font-face, as @boomerang has commented above.